# Jquery animate effect

Tags: jquery, css

I have navigation bar in my website. following is the code with css

CSS

```
#navbar
{
width : auto;
height : 80px;
margin:15px 0px 0px 400px;
float:left;
}

#navbar ul
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
display:inline;
}

#navbar ul li
{
list-style:none;
float:left;
display:inline;

}

#navbar ul li a {
float:left;
display:inline;
font-family:arial;
font-size:16px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#505050;
margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px ;
padding : 5px;
width : 90px;
text-align:center;
border-radius:3px;
text-decoration:none;
}

#navbar ul li a:hover
{
background : #C84A30;
color:white;
}

#navbar ul li a.current {
background : #1D78B8;
color:white;
}
```

The HTML

```
<div id="navbar">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>   
<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>    
<li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is the Jquery i am using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#navbar ul li a").hover(function() { 
$(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#C84A30" }, 100); 
}, function() {
$(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "transparent" }, 300); 
});
})
```

What i want is whenver the users hover any item of navigation bar, the background color should animate with red color. but, this also applies to current item ie. the current class. I dont want that the current class should be affected by jquery.

For eg :
The current page is Home Page, then the home tab is modified with css current class.
When the user hovers on any other tab i.e About us . the background should animate to red color.but the home tab should not be affceted.

Pls help

Comment: It seems to be working - http://jsfiddle.net/fnydu/ - what's the issue?

Comment: its working, the issue is i dont want the jquery to work on 'current' class in css. If home page is current page then the jquery should not work on home tab

Comment: k, @Reigel's answer should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this... using `.not()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#navbar ul li a").not(".current").hover(function() { 
         $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#C84A30" }, 100); 
    }, function() {
         $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "transparent" }, 300); 
    });
})
```

[link demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/ACNsY/)

Comment: One more thing i have, when the page is loaded, and when i first time hover on the elements the jquery doesnt works. it only starts working when i unhover the element. Pls help on it

Comment: @NiravChheda I'm not sure why... the demo works as expected... maybe js file is loading slow...

Comment: any other ideas as to pre load jquery file